# Can modules be used as type restrictions?

Tags: crystal-lang

I'm trying to implement a generic priority queue container class where the elements to be stored must have an ordering property. Right now I have

```
class PriorityQueue(T)
    ...
end
```

This works when I create `PriorityQueue(Int32)`, `PriorityQueue(String)`, or `PriorityQueue(Foo)` where I implement `Foo` to `include Comparable(Foo)`, but I'm wondering if there's a way for the `PriorityQueue` class to declare that `T`'s must be `Comparable`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, Crystal currently (as of 0.31) does not support restricting the types of free vars. This feature is being discussed at https://github.com/crystal-lang/crystal/issues/934

In the meantime as you noted it still works by using the Ruby style of expecting an interface by just calling the methods you need, it's just that the error messages produced by that can be a bit hard to understand.

Comment: Well that would explain why I couldn't find such a feature...